# How can we use gnosis safe with unsupported chains?

Tags: blockchain, smart-contract-wallets

For example i created a fantom gnosis safe wallet, how can we access it and for example we sent tokens in the fantom gnosis wallet, how can we recover or transfer it if we can't see it in the app.safe.global website